# NodeJS server loading Loop

Tags: node.js

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const requests = require('requests');

const homefile = fs.readFileSync("./home.html", 'utf-8');
const replaceVal = (tempVal, orgVal) => {
    let temperature = tempVal.replace(`{%tempVal%}`, orgVal.main.temp);
    return temperature;
}
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url == '/') {
        requests('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Pune&appid=4bebabe44d8d1f07b79b9bbc8ed9dd33')
            .on('data', function (chunk) {
                const objdata = JSON.parse(chunk);
                const arrayDatda = [objdata];
                console.log(arrayDatda);
                const realtimeData = arrayDatda.map((val) => replaceVal(homefile, val)).join("")
                // console.log(realtimeData)
                res.write(realtimeData)
            })
            .on('end', function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('connection closed due to errors', err);
                }
                res.end("working");
            });
    }
})
server.listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
```

**Whenever I try to restart the server it just goes on loading loop and didn't show any results until I stop the loading**

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with your problem, but you can't reliably do `const objdata = JSON.parse(chunk);` because you have no guarantee that a chunk will be a whole piece of parsable JSON.  It could just be some of a whole piece of JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running your code without the file replacement logic you've written and got this error.

```sh
_http_outgoing.js:679
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('first argument',
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer. Received an instance of Array
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:679:11)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:644:15)
```

You have to send a supported content-type to `res.write`.

`const realtimeData = arrayDatda.map((val) => replaceVal(homefile, val)).join("")`

`realtimeData` is an Array and is not supported.

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const requests = require('requests');

// const homefile = fs.readFileSync("./home.html", 'utf-8');
// const replaceVal = (tempVal, orgVal) => {
//     let temperature = tempVal.replace(`{%tempVal%}`, orgVal.main.temp);
//     return temperature;
// }
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url == '/') {
        requests('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Pune&appid=4bebabe44d8d1f07b79b9bbc8ed9dd33')
            .on('data', function (chunk) {
                const objdata = JSON.parse(chunk);
                const arrayDatda = [objdata];
                console.log(arrayDatda);
                // const realtimeData = arrayDatda.map((val) => replaceVal(homefile, val)).join("")
                // console.log(realtimeData)
                // converting arrayDatda to string and sending works
                res.write(JSON.stringify(arrayDatda))
            })
            .on('end', function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('connection closed due to errors', err);
                }
                res.end("working");
            });
    }
})
server.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
```

So after replacing your file with data that you've received from API, you have to serve that file in `res.write`, not the `realtimeDatda` variable which is an Array.

I suggest going through the basics of node http server again and learn about how to serve different content types and static files.

Here is a good beginner blog:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-web-server-in-node-js-with-the-http-module